# php/mysql Counting number of items matching a condition

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a database that logs the number of people attending a meeting.
The table is set up like this:

```
name | status
 ----+---------
 Joe | No
 Jon | Yes
Mike | Yes
```

What I am looking to do is count the number of times the status is "Yes" and then output that to the screen.

```
$yes_attending = 'SELECT status FROM attendees WHERE "status=Yes"';
$yes_result= $link->query($yes_attending);
    if($yes_result=mysqli_query($link,$yes_attending))
    {
        $yesCount = mysqli_num_rows($yes_result);
    } else{
        echo '0';
    }
```

My issue is that this code is returning 0 even though I do have information in the database that matches the "Yes" condition.

Comment: get rid of those quotes around the status=YES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making your condition to be a literal text and so the error. Change it to

```
$yes_attending = "SELECT status FROM attendees WHERE status='Yes'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to misunderstand what the `mysqli_query()` does, it returns if it's executed or not.

```
$sql = "SELECT status FROM attendees WHERE status='Yes'";

if($rsl = mysqli_query($link,$sql) != false){
    echo 'Query successfully executed';
    if($c = mysqli_num_rows($rsl) > 0){
      echo "The amount of results: '$c'";
    } else {
      echo "There are no attendees that have an active status";
    }
} else {
    printf("Query failed: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
}
```

Also, why are you asking to select *status*?
I ask because the result is going to be 'Yes'.

Comment: To be fair, the OP has to select _something_, and `status` is as good as anything else. Though this would be more efficient if it used `SELECT count(status) FROM...` instead - let the database do the counting for you, so it's just returning a single row.

Comment: @andrewsi you can always select 0, but I would expect an ID or something,

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the quotes around the `status=YES`

Right now your mysql statement is invalid.